# How to append more data to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I have this:

```
tradedict = {'id': 325920, 'order_id': 109185014, 'matched_order_id': 109181538, 
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 48, 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR', 'amount': '1',
'price': '0.1507', 'date': 1654433352373}
```

and I want to add this to the dictionary:

```
{'id': 325910, 'order_id': 109179557, 'matched_order_id': 109179004,
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 50, 'symbol': 'BTC/ECS', 'amount': '0.001',
'price': '193499.99', 'date': 1654429749384}
```

So it will look like this: (If it possible.)

```
tradedict = {'id': 325920, 'order_id': 109185014, 'matched_order_id': 109181538, 
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 48, 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR', 'amount': '1',
'price': '0.1507', 'date': 1654433352373}, 

{'id': 325910, 'order_id': 109179557, 'matched_order_id': 109179004,
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 50, 'symbol': 'BTC/ECS', 'amount': '0.001',
'price': '193499.99', 'date': 1654429749384}
```

I'm not good to python, so I don't know if this is possible. If it is possible how do I search for element: 'trading_pair_id': 50 and if the 'id' for that index has changed I want to update all elements with new data for that index.

Comment: I think you need a list of dictionary to add your dictionary to. Check this for example: https://pythonexamples.org/python-list-of-dictionaries/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the output you mentioned in your question is a valid dictionary.. It's more like a tuple.. So I came up with my code to join these two dictionaries.

```
tradedict = {'id': 325920, 'order_id': 109185014, 'matched_order_id': 109181538, 
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 48, 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR', 'amount': '1',
'price': '0.1507', 'date': 1654433352373}

another_tradedict = {'id': 325910, 'order_id': 109179557, 'matched_order_id': 109179004,
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 50, 'symbol': 'BTC/ECS', 'amount': '0.001',
'price': '193499.99', 'date': 1654429749384}


for i in tradedict:
    temp = []
    temp.append(tradedict[i])
    temp.append(another_tradedict[i])
    tradedict[i] = temp

print(tradedict)
```

And the output would be something like this,

```
{'id': [325920, 325910], 'order_id': [109185014, 109179557], 'matched_order_id': [109181538, 109179004], 'direction': ['BUY', 'BUY'], 'trading_pair_id': [48, 50], 'symbol': ['ECS/EUR', 'BTC/ECS'], 'amount': ['1', '0.001'], 'price': ['0.1507', '193499.99'], 'date': [1654433352373, 1654429749384]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## You cannot repeat keys in a dictionary

### What I meant to say is,

Your primary dictionary is having a key name "id", "order_id" etc

```py
tradedict = {'id': 325920, 'order_id': 109185014, 'matched_order_id': 109181538, 
'direction': 'BUY', 'trading_pair_id': 48, 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR', 'amount': '1',
'price': '0.1507', 'date': 1654433352373}
```

But the dictionary you wish to add also has the same keys, hence you will not be able to add these two dictionaries in particular.

### But what you can do is:

You can add new key-value pairs in your dictionary

```py
tradeict["Company"]="amazon"
```

You will get this as a result

```py
{'id': 325920,
 'order_id': 109185014,
 'matched_order_id': 109181538,
 'direction': 'BUY',
 'trading_pair_id': 48,
 'symbol': 'ECS/EUR',
 'amount': '1',
 'price': '0.1507',
 'date': 1654433352373,
 'company': 'amazon'}
```

Notice how new key value pair has been added to the dictionary